# Faster way to creating a binary vector of fixed length: if fixed length is say 6, 4' would become (0,0,0,1,0,0)

Tags: r, vector, binary

I have a huge data of survey answers to multiple choice questions. Every row represents a person's answer to around 73 questions. Every column represents the answer to a question: example if they answered (d) they get a 4. I want to turn every observation (row,column) into a vector of 1s and 0s, so (d) would become (0,0,0,1).

I've been creating 2 logical for loops. But its taking a LOT of time.

Does anyone know a faster/smarter/more efficient way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of your dataframe and show what the expected output would look like ?

Comment: i've added a picture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using simple sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(answers = c(1,2,5,4,3,2,6,1,4))

  answers
1       1
2       2
3       5
4       4
5       3
6       2
7       6
8       1
9       4
```

Then create the empty vectors

```
df$recode <- list(rep(0, 6))

  answers           recode
1       1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
2       2 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
3       5 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
4       4 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
5       3 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
6       2 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
7       6 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
8       1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
9       4 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Then manipulate them according to the information in your answers.

```
df$recode <- Map(function(x,y) `[<-`(x,y,1), x = df$recode, y = df$answers)

  answers           recode
1       1 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
2       2 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
3       5 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
4       4 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
5       3 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
6       2 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
7       6 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
8       1 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
9       4 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

Comment: I tried something like this. Its taking 20+ minutes for my dataframe :(

Comment: For me it does 20k rows in 0.04 secs.

Comment: The thing is, for every answer, there's a different number of possible answers. Its not constant for every question..

Comment: Well, then you have to repeat this for every answer changing `list(rep(0, *number of possible answers*))` every time.

Comment: one more question. Just realised that some people didn't answer at all = so their answer is recorded as 0. in which case, I'd like the vector to just be 0s. Any ideas how I can deal with that? much appreciated! UPDATE: i think change `[[<-` to `[<-` fixed it!

Comment: Okay, I will inlcude it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

to_dummy from the sjmisc package could do the work.

```
library(sjmisc)
df1=data.frame(Q1=c(1,2,3,4),Q2=c(2,2,3,4))
to_dummy(df1)
```

As you can see, it creates only 3 variables for Q2, which is unfortnuate (it has only 3 modalities). So this will work only if if all modalities are present for each question.

A quick hack would be to add four row to your DATA (one by modality) and delete them afterwards.

```
df2=rbind(df1,rep(1,ncol(df1)),rep(2,ncol(df1)),rep(3,ncol(df1)),rep(4,ncol(df1)))

to_dummy(df2)[1:(nrow(df2)-4),]
```

Comment: I don't see why would it change anything concerning my answer.

Comment: i guess i dont fully understand the rep() part

Comment: rbind : you will add rows ; rep(1,ncol(df1), you will add a row composed solely of 1 which is the size of your dataframe (ncol(df1)).  and then these rows are deleted at the end. This is to ensure that all modalities are represented whien converting to dummy. Just try out rep(1,10)

Comment: oh no no i understand how the functions work, but not sure how to implement this to a 50,000 x 70 dataset